# Can I put an INSERT inside an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I'm having a some troubles with a complicated query, that required me to insert something in a table, but if I found that two columns are the same I should stop the transaction with a trigger. I make some code to do that, but I'm not sure 100% of it even when it works fine now.

```
  alter trigger TR1  
  on Passer instead of insert 
  as
  begin 
  declare @A int
  declare @B int
  declare @C int 
  set @A = (select code_ligne from inserted)
  set @B = (select ordre_passage from inserted)
  set @C = (select code_ville from inserted)
  select * from passer 
  where code_ligne = @A
  and  ordre_passage = @B

  if(@@rowcount = 0 )
  begin
  insert into Passer values(@A,@C,@B)
  print 'okay'
  print @@rowcount
  end
  end
```

Comment: Trigger Misconceptions 101: inserted has only ONE row.  Inserted can have more than one Row.

Comment: thanks for the comment sir, So you mean i'il have a problem when i'l insert more than one row ??

Comment: Yes, you will have problems with more than one row. Why not setup a Unique Constraint on code_ligne and ordre_passage? If someone tries to insert that composite key again, it will throw an unique key error.

Comment: i jut tried it with two rows but No problem sir thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have scalar variables like this in a trigger you are going to run into problems. If you have two rows inserted at once you will only get 1 row inserted into Passer. You don't need these variables at all. Just switch this around to be a single set based insert statement. Something along these lines.

```
alter trigger TR1 on Passer instead of insert as 
begin 

    insert into Passer
    (
        code_ligne
        , ordre_passage
        , code_ville
    )
    select i.code_ligne
        , i.ordre_passage
        , i.code_ville
    from inserted i
    join Passer p on p.code_ligne = i.code_ligne
                and p.ordre_passage = i.ordre_passage

    if(@@rowcount = 0 ) begin
        print 'okay'
        print @@rowcount
    end
end
```

Comment: sir thank you very much i'm a beginner and your way its a very easy and nice way to do it , i'm in love with your code sir

Comment: @adilzakarya - If this works for you then you should consider marking this as the answer.

Comment: i did it Sorry sir my mistake i'm new here